# Set Bin folder to a local sub folder in ASP.NET windows hosting

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, windows-hosting

I am deploying multiple ASP.NET web applications on my godaddy.com web host.
The problem is that the default "bin" folder is the one on the root.
I want each application to use the bin folder which is in side it. For example, if i have app1 in folder called app1/ and compiled code is in app1/bin, I want to redirect it to the sub-folder not the one in the root.

Thanks,
Badih

Comment: Check GoDaddy documentation please. Maybe it only allows you to deploy a single web app intentionally.

Comment: My question is how to tell my app to use another bin folder which is inside the app folder, rather than the bin folder at the root.